# How would I transfer and replace my link specifications from one MS Access file to another using vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I currently have an Access file with about 30 custom link specs.  I would like to transfer these specs into about 30 different access files using VBA.  The end goal of this would be to automate quarterly txt data being put into Access according to certain link specifications.  I need a code that will replace the tables MSysIMEXSpecs and MSysIMEXColumns in the new Access file with the tables in the main Access file that contains all the VBA code.  If you could go one step farther and explain how to then use these specs to import a comma delimited txt file using the spec, that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe these two lines of code (Display below) did the job:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", DatabaseFullPath, acTable, "MSysIMEXColumns", "MSysIMEXColumns"

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", DatabaseFullPath, acTable, "MSysIMEXSpecs", "MSysIMEXSpecs"
```